# kendo dropdown list select option label by default

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a dropdown list created using kendo library. I have added a option label default text which I want to show on load by default. If I use a select element to initialize a dropdown it does not work nicely but when I use input type as text then it work.

HTML:

```
<select id="size">
    <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
    <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
    <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
    <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#size").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: " -- Select -- "
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42DkV/

Answer (score 7):

Try

[.select()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-select)

```
$("#size").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: " -- Select -- "
}).data("kendoDropDownList").select(0); //select(index) , index starts from 0
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Tcjqq/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#size").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: " -- Select -- ",
    value:"-- Select --"

});
```